# Outlook 2016 won't connect to Office 365 likely due to multiple domains

Tags: office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have tried *everything* to get this working again.  I have an account, `MyCorp\nibblypig` and an email address `nibblypig@mycorp.com` which is office 365.

If I log onto my machine as this, Outlook 2016 automatically found it after typing it my email address and password, and all was good in the world.  However, I do work for SadCorp and I have to log on as `SadCorp\nibblypig`.  I don't actually use `MyCorp\nibblypig` because all my work is done for SadCorp (I used it once just now to see if e-mail would work).

Previously, e-mail was working fine when logged on as SadCorp, with MyCorp's email address, then AD settings required me to change my password as it was expiring.  I did and Outlook stopped working, saying 'Need Password' and a button appeared to enter my exchange password.  Clicking this button did nothing, the UI flickered, but nothing.

I've tried:

- Updating my password on both domains, as both have the same new password.
- Signing out and in, nothing, need password button still there.
- Removing everything from Credential Manager, and re-signing in, need password button still there.
- Some registry keys suggested online `DisableADALatopWAMOverride` and `EnableADAL`, still no dice.
- Repairing Office in Control Panel, nope.
- Removing my Outlook account, and, following a guide, I opened Mail 32bit in Control Panel, set a new location for the data, then removed my account. I also followed instructions to remove the registry entries in `16.0\common\identities`.

Now, when I try to set up a new Office account, it cannot do automatic setup, as it just spins and then says it can't find it. It gives me a manual settings option, which I also tried, but the guides say you need to press 'more settings' and set an option or two, but there is no 'more settings' option.

I wondered if I could somehow copy the Outlook setup from my working mycorp profile to sadcorp, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can simply get my Office 365 email on my sadcorp account, I would love to hear it.

I'm running windows 7 because mycorp and sadcorp won't update it.

Comment: It seems that this is a Outlook client issue. For your reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook

Comment: Something in the mailbox settings for the account is wrong _(see @Aidan's comment above)_ , as Outlook supports connecting to the multiple Exchange, or any other, accounts at the same time.  File > Account Settings > Email tab > highlight email account > Change > More Settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to fix it, which is to run Outlook as another user.  It's not ideal, and I certainly didn't need to do this before I changed my password. However, it worked immediately when I did so.

I created a shortcut as follows:

```bat
runas /user:MyCorp\nibblypig /savecreds "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\Outlook.exe"
```

It isn't perfect, since it allows me to launch multiple instances if I click it twice, and it doesn't recognize pinning to the taskbar properly (you get 2 icons if you launch it, ungrouped).

Considering both methods use autodiscovery based on the e-mail address and it worked before I don't see why it wouldn't work with my sadcorp login but this might help someone out in the future who is frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today after a user changed their password.  Same steps were tried above so those may also have some affect on the fix.  In our environment the computer is joined locally to a domain and AD is synced with O365.

Here is what appears to have fixed it for me.  I went to Start > Settings > Accounts > Email & accounts.  On the right side the user account was already listed under under work or school account but there wasn't a way to remove it and re-add it.  So I just tried adding it again.  It said it was successful.  I went to Word and it let me add the services again.  I opened Outlook and it didn't ask for the password anymore it just connected.

Hope this helps someone else with this issue.